# How to import external typescript files in expo project

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

Is there a way to transpile and support imports from a folder that is outside the expo project's main folder?

I'm looking to just import some additional files from a shared folder.

Here's my setup, and problem:

**The root folder**

Has 3 subfolders, no `package.json`, no `tsconfig.json`, just those:

- /server --> a nodejs rest api
- /mobile --> an expo project
- /shared --> a folder with lots of common typescript files

**The mobile folder**

This one has the expo project generated with **typescript**. Project works fine up until I import something from `./shared`.

Importing a file from `./shared` in the expo folder does not work: (running `npm run start` in `./mobile fodler`)

```
// mobile/src/screents/login
import { inject } from "../../../../shared/src/core/di"
```

The error I get is this:

Web:

[image: screenshot with web error]

Ios:
[image: screenshot with ios error]

My assumption is that the file is found yet the babel/typescript transpilation is not triggered. I am uncertain where this aspect can be specified.

My `mobile/babel.config.js` is the standard one generated by expo:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

There is no `mobile/metro.config.js`.

I looked over the docs and got lost in between expo and metro configurations.

Answer (score 2):

You can create metro.config.js file in the Expo root project folder if there is none. More details can be found here in Expo documentation.

[See the Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro/)

Than just follow this simple and well explained tutorial on Medium.com by Dushyant Bansal. I faced the same issue as you do and it did the job for me.

[How to import files from outside of root directory with React Native Metro bundler](https://medium.com/@dushyant_db/how-to-import-files-from-outside-of-root-directory-with-react-native-metro-bundler-18207a348427)

Regards,

Tom

Comment: Followed the same steps which is provided in the link. It is working for js import. Where as if i try to import ts file from external folder, ts file cannot take root module dependencies. So it is throwing error. Any idea?

Comment: Is also not working for me when I'm trying to import a markdown file. (Works if in the same project folder.)